# Cannot login in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I cannot login into my CakePHP app. `$this->Auth->identify();` keeps returning false.

My **User** Entity:

```
...
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
...
protected function _setPassword($value)
    {
        if (strlen($value)) {
            $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
            return $hasher->hash($value);
        }
    }
```

**Note:** my Users table contains email and password fields, both varchar(255).

My **AppController**:

```
public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');

        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ],
            'authError' => 'Log in to proceed',
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer(),
            'storage' => 'Session'
        ]);
        $this->Auth->allow(['login', 'view', 'index']);
    }
```

My **UsersController**:

```
public function login()
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('login');
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error('Incorrect login data.');
    }
}

public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->Auth->allow(['logout']);
}

public function logout()
{
    $this->Flash->success('You are now logged out.');
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
}
```

And **login.ctp**, for good measure:

```
<div class="users form">
<?= $this->Flash->render('auth') ?>
    <?= $this->Form->create() ?>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <?= $this->Form->control('username', ['class' => 'form-control']) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->control('password', ['class' => 'form-control']) ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Login')); ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

When I `var_dump($_POST)` just after `$user = $this->Auth->identify();` I get correct data to post. I checked password_verify myself to make sure it is correct. It is. But still false is returned I keep getting Incorrect login data error.

Please don't mark the question as duplicate since I read all other questions and answers, but none of them solved my problem.

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have configured the `Form` authenticator to use the `email` field for identifying the user, but your form doesn't use that field, it uses the `username` field, hence the authenticator will not find the posted data.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Authentication > Configuring Authentication Handlers](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers)**
- **[Cookbook > Tutorials & Examples > CMS Tutorial - Authentication > Adding Login](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/authentication.html#adding-login)**

Comment: I'm slightly embarassed now. Somehow I thought that after setting 'username' => 'email', in 'fields' Cake will assign the correct values, especially since I baked the form. Thank you kind sir.